# raise ValueError("cannot have a multithreaded and multi process server.") ValueError: cannot have a multithreaded and multi process server

Tags: python, flask

- Serving Flask app "server" (lazy loading)

  - Environment: production
    WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
    Use a production WSGI server instead.
  - Debug mode: on
  - Running on http://0.0.0.0:9002/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
  - Restarting with stat
  - Debugger is active!
  - Debugger PIN: 314-390-242
    Exception in thread Thread-1:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/user/Downloads/yes/envs/emotionservice/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
    File "/home/user/Downloads/yes/envs/emotionservice/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
    File "/home/user/Downloads/yes/envs/emotionservice/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 963, in inner
    fd=fd,
    File "/home/user/Downloads/yes/envs/emotionservice/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 803, in make_server
    raise ValueError("cannot have a multithreaded and multi process server.")
    ValueError: cannot have a multithreaded and multi process server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it solved.
set threaded=True
processes=1

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use flask in multiprocessing mode (processes > 1). include threaded=False, otherwise it throws same error.

> > > app.run(host=addr, port=port, threaded=False, processes=50)